# HTML/CSS - Styling a large collection of hyperlinks?

Tags: html, css

I have a *Master Links* HTML page in use for my Intranet sites.

On the page are **67** distinct links which are grouped under **7** section headers.

Currently the links are organized via tables.

Is there a better way to organize the links while making them visually distinctive?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question? Are you asking what styles you can apply to the headers and links to make them more distinct? If that is the question, I don't think this is an html/css question, but a design question.

Comment: I guess my question is more - what best practices have you used to get a large amount of hyperlinks to not blend together - It is a design question but requires some realworld CSS/HTML coding.

Comment: This sounds more like a design issue than a programming one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you differ between links based on what section they are in:

```
<ul class="linksectionA">
  <li><a href="#">Link A1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link A2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link A3</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="linksectionB">
  <li><a href="#">Link B1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link B2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link B3</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="linksectionC">
  <li><a href="#">Link C1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link C2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link C3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then you can easily assign each link within those sections a different style:

```
.linksectionA a { color: red; }
.linksectionB a { color: green; }
.linksectionC a { color: blue; }
```

Comment: The ul/li combo is not necessary, you can replace the `ul` with any other element. I just used it so I have an easy formatted example ;) The only important thing is that the links are inside of a specific element with the said class. If that element is an ´ul´ or ´div´ or ´p´ or whatever doesn't matter.

Comment: Okay, with the changed question, it makes sense ;) Yes, the use of a list is definitely one of the easiest options. You can even put multiple lists next to each other by letting them float for example.

Answer (score 2):

```
a:link              { color:blue; text-decoration:underline; font-weight: bold; }
a:visited           { color:gray; text-decoration:underline; font-weight: bold; }
a:hover             { color:green; text-decoration:underline; font-weight: bold; }
a:active            { color:red; text-decoration:underline; font-weight: bold; }

a.otherLink:link    { color:black; text-decoration:none; }
a.otherLink:visited { color:yellow; text-decoration:none; }
a.otherLink:hover   { color:#123456; text-decoration:underline; }
a.otherLink:active  { color:lime; text-decoration:none; }
```

note that the `a:` styles are for the default links, and the `a.otherLink:` style will apply to links in the form of `<a class="otherLink" href="...">`

Answer (score 1):

You can identify all the links as a specific class if you wish to change the style of only the links on that page. Additionally, if you don't crea if all of the links change style, then redefine the style for the link tag.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest grouping them by unordered lists, like poke suggested, and using graceful enhancement with a style like−

```
.linksectionA li:n-th-child(even) {  }
```

Comment: interesting - does IE7 support this pseudo-class?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it doesn't, that pseudo-class is CSS3 and IE7 isn't friendly to CSS3 at all.